# Cant Detect other computer on network

Tags: windows-10, home-networking

I cant see computer on my network.

I just bought Lenovo X1 win 10 Pro version 1803 - 64 bit. It can't detect other computer except 1 computer running win 10 education version 1709 (computer name KUIS-03). Other computer run win 10 home, win 7, win server 2010, etc.

Last time it connect I set quick access (KUIS-02, see picture.) I was able to connect using quick access but then the computer KUIS-02 broken, I have set it same IP and computer name but couldn't connect again

I have turn off private and domain firewall, windows defender, install smbv1 but still it doesn't work.

help please

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have permissions to access other computer, check the following services in the `services.msc`, if they are not running, set them start and set them as `automatic`.

1. Open `Computer Management`
2. Open `Services and Applications`
3. Open `Services`
4. See the following services(especially the first service and the second service)
   (1) **Function Discovery Provider Host**
   (2) **Function Discovery Resource Publication**
   (3) **DNS Client**
   (4) **SSDP Discovery**
   (5) **Workstation**

And some services if you want to run, you need to run the `relay on` services.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check network is set to Private
2. Check workgroup has the same name on all computers
   Control Panel - System Properties - Computer Name